# Spring integration file with JMS outbound adapter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jms, spring-integration-dsl

I'm working on a project where I poll files on a directory using spring integration file into an inbound
channel, do some stuff with it, and then publish the result to MQ using a `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>`
But I can't find any useful examples on how to implement this solution without going through xml configuration files.

Im not sure if the folowing example would be the solution for this case though

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsOutboundGatewayFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("jmsOutboundGatewayChannel")
            .handle(Jms.outboundGateway(this.jmsConnectionFactory)
                        .replyContainer(c ->
                                    c.concurrentConsumers(3)
                                            .sessionTransacted(true))
                        .requestDestination("jmsPipelineTest"))
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gateway is for request/reply processing; use one of the `Jms.outboundAdapter()` methods for send only.

Comment: Great, I have already a JmsTemplate created, so I can use it as a parameter for outboundAdapter(). Thanks Russel